# "Invalid return_url" (Bad Request 400) after loging in to ArgoCD via Keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, redirect, devops, keycloak, argocd

I am trying to authenticate in ArgoCD using Keycloak. I am following [this guide](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/keycloak/), but there is a problem. ArgoCD redirects me to http://URL/**auth**/login?return_url=... which throws this Bad Request 400 - Invalid return_url. The correct link though is http://URL/login?return_url=..., but I don't see where I should change it so it doesn't append **auth** to the path.

The **Valid Redirect URIs** field is set to ***** in the Keycloak client for ArgoCD.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, the culprit:
the missing “url: https//:yourargocdurl”
in the comfigMap argocd-cm

Comment: Thank you, this was the culprit. It gets increasingly complex to configure these sorts of integrations nowadays that I start to slowly start hate this profession.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I redeployed Argo CD and changed the new url. As far as I remember, it's not safe to use * for **Valid Redirect URIs** , what I did is put **https://your_domain/***

After that, I got some weird error: **unknown app state xxxxx**, and I saw the configMap is wrong, it should be
**clientSecret: $oidc.keycloak.clientSecret**

but I'm using Helm, so it was only **.keycloak.clientSecret**

Comment: I am having the same issue with .keycloak.clientSecret now as well

Comment: @EliHalych Yea, so change that to $oidc.keycloak.clientSecret and it will work

Comment: Any idea why  `$oidc.keycloak.clientSecret` becomes `.keycloak.clientSecret` after Helm installs the chart? How do I keep the `$oidc` part? It seems that Helm thinks it is a variable that is null. Did you try to escape the dollar sign or something?

Comment: I actually didn't figure out. For now, I just remind myself that I need to change the value. I know it's not ideal, but I have tried a few ways and none of it was working. Thus, manually for now